# How to get JMX Counter in PerfMon Metrics Collector

Tags: jmeter, performance, jmeter-plugins, performance-testing

I am trying to get JMX monitors graph in Perfmon Metrics collector listener but getting all server metrics like CPU, Memory , network I/O except JMX.
When I am going to apply this counter then getting the following error in perfmon agent:

**ERROR**

```
2018-02-21 11:18:02.135 [kg.apc.p] (): Failed to get JMX Connector
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]
```

Started Perfmon agent on default port 4711 which is applicable for jmx as per the below statement :

```
/*Since version 0.5.2 Server Agent has ability to monitor some JMX values inside Java Virtual Machine. ****To enable JMX monitoring you must start Java with some special properties enabled, like described here. Here's simplest (and not so secure) options to start Java with JMX enabled**:**
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4711 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false <other options>*/ Copied from github page.
```

Can anyone help me where i have to make the change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your **application under test**, not PerfMon Server Agent with these parameters

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4711 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Depending on your application deployment you need to add these properties to application server, the majority of them respect [JAVA_OPTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241743/how-do-i-use-the-java-opts-environment-variable) environment variable, refer your application or application server documentation to learn how to apply these JMX parameters.

You can test JMX server connectivity using [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) or [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html), if you are able to connect to your application RMI endpoint using port 4711 - PerfMon will be able to do this as well.

You can also consider using [JMXMon Sample Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/) listener which is a little bit more advanced.

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more information if needed.